# The location of scan disk log file in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I schedule a scan disk operation before Windows XP OS is launched. After the operation finishes I want examine the log file of the scan disk operation. Where it is located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the scan disk log using the [Event Viewer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427) under the Application log.

Here is an example log file:

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         
Cleaning up minor inconsistencies on the drive.
Cleaning up 35 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 35 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 35 unused security descriptors.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.

  80035798 KB total disk space.
  16830724 KB in 57819 files.
     18252 KB in 5163 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    294678 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  62892144 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  20008949 total allocation units on disk.
  15723036 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
d0 dc 01 00 12 f6 00 00 e4 38 01 00 00 00 00 00  .........8......
98 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 09 07 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
b2 14 40 03 00 00 00 00 a2 75 10 23 00 00 00 00  ..@......u.#....
62 c5 f6 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b...............
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 e2 31 3b 00 00 00 00  ..........1;....
99 9e 36 00 00 00 00 00 10 3a 07 00 db e1 00 00  ..6......:......
00 00 00 00 00 10 44 03 04 00 00 00 2b 14 00 00  ......D.....+...

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be in the event viewer, Event id 1001.